# Why do we need to add [] to a iterable array and * to asyncio.gather?

Tags: python-asyncio

Using this example

```
import time
import asyncio


async def main(x):
    print(f"Starting Task {x}")
    await asyncio.sleep(3)
    print(f"Finished Task {x}")


async def async_io():
    tasks = []
    for i in range(10):
        tasks += [main(i)]
    await asyncio.gather(*tasks)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    start_time = time.perf_counter()
    asyncio.run(async_io())
    print(f"Took {time.perf_counter() - start_time} secs")
```

I noticed that we need to create a list that keeps track of the tasks to do. Understandable, but then why do we add the [] wrapper over the main(i) function? And also in the asyncio.gather(*tasks), why do we need to add the asterisk there as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> why do we add the [] wrapper over the main(i) function?

There are a few ways to add items into a list. One such way, the way you've chosen, is by concatenating two lists together.

```
>>> [1] + [2]
[1, 2]
```

Trying to concatenate a list and something else will lead to a `TypeError`.

In your particular case you're using augmented assignment, a (often more performant) shorthand for

```
tasks = tasks + [main(i)]
```

Another way to accomplish this is with `append`.

```
tasks.append(main(i))
```

If your real code matches your example code, an even better way to spell all of this is

```
tasks = [main(i) for i in range(10)]
```

> in the asyncio.gather(*tasks), why do we need to add the asterisk there as well?

Because `gather` will to run each positional argument it receives. Calls to `gather` should look like

```
asyncio.gather(main(0))

asyncio.gather(main(0), main(1))
```

Since there are times when you need to use a variable number of positional arguments, Python offers the unpacking operator (`*` in the case of lists).

If you felt so inclined, your example can be rewritten as

```
async def async_io():
    await asyncio.gather(*[main(i) for i in range(10)])
```